# Git grep on files from last commit only

Tags: git, grep

I would like to run git grep like this

```
git grep -ni 'something' -- "*.spec"
```

only on the files that were changed in last commit, with this same result as above command. Do you have any good idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best I can think of is to get the list of files and use them with regular `grep`<sup>1</sup>.  The tricky part (of course) is handling filenames with spaces and newlines..

```
git diff-tree -z --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD \
   | xargs -0 grep --include 'pattern' -- "regex"
```

Where *pattern* is the one you would use to match the filenames and *regex* is the actual regular expression to search for in the files.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The reason for not using `git-grep` (other that it's not necessary) is that it expands patterns in the filenames whereas we need exact matching.</sup>